# Initialize formatter while handling exception?

Tags: java

I'm an absolute beginner in Java and apologize if this question seems ridiculous. I am facing the following problem :

When I try

```
public class oranges {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Formatter x=new Formatter("note1.txt");
    x.close();}}
```

it says there's an unhandled exception.
But when I try

```
public class oranges {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Formatter x;
    try {
        x=new Formatter("note1.txt");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    x.close();}}
```

it says that x has not been initialized. How can I initialize x while handling exception? I prefer not to use a separate method to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry! Don't know what that is yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the constructor throws an exception, you don't have an object, so there is nothing to close.

You have multiple options:

```java
// Cascade exception to caller (JVM will print it for you when main() throws exception)
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Formatter x = new Formatter("note1.txt");
    // use x here
    x.close();
}
```

```java
// Put close() inside try block
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Formatter x = new Formatter("note1.txt");
        // use x here
        x.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e); // Print the exception too
    }
}
```

```java
// Wrap in an unchecked exception
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Formatter x = new Formatter("note1.txt");
        // use x here
        x.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error", e); // Include original exception as the cause
    }
}
```

```java
// Initialize variable to null
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Formatter x = null;
    try {
        x = new Formatter("note1.txt");
        // use x here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out); // Better way to print the exception
    }
    if (x != null) {
        // or use x here
        x.close();
    }
}
```

```java
// If formatter is auto-closeable, use try-with-resources
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Formatter x = new Formatter("note1.txt")) {
        // use x here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

For simple programs with a `main()` method, I would recommend the first one.

Actually, since most exceptions are unrecoverable, you should almost always cascade the exception and let the caller handle it. If the exception is checked but you don't want all caller to have to declare it on the methods, you can catch it and throw an unchecked exception.

Comment: If this is a `java.util.Formatter`, it implements `AutoCloseable`; might be worth offering a try-with-resources as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Include `x.close()` inside the `try` block.